How do I increase the vertex size in the interface?
In one video I saw that one person has his vertex much bigger than usual, how can I do the same?
In video:

Me:


I converted your answer into a comment, as neither that or @curious_1's provide a receivable answer to the question: a good answer on BSE should be self-sufficient and not require going to an external resource. Both of you are welcome to post an elaborated answer with proper instructions, screenshots and whatever you deem to help to make it a comprehensible answer.

To change the Vertex Size in 3D viewport:
Open Edit > Preferences > Themes and open the 3D Viewport dropdown:

In that dropdown scroll down below the color settings to Vertex Size:

Adjust the size to your preference:


If you are interested in doing it via Python you can set the value of vertex_size to your desired size:
import bpy

theme = bpy.context.preferences.themes[0]
view3d_theme = theme.view_3d

view3d_theme.vertex_size = 5 # default=3

